# How to stop Angular $digest() iterations reached

Tags: angularjs

I have read what causes this but I cannot apply any of the solutions to my issue. I am trying to populate a select box with the boolean value of a object. The solution I found gives this error in the console.

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
 Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 16; oldVal:   14"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 18; oldVal: 16"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 20; oldVal: 18"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 22; oldVal: 20"],["fn: $watchCollectionWatch; newVal: 24; oldVal: 22"]]


<label style="margin-left:46px">Super:</label>
<select style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedEmployee.EmployeeIsSuper" ng-options="o.v as o.n for o in [{ n: 'No', v: false }, { n: 'Yes', v: true }]">
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
```

Comment: why can't you just put the options array into the scope? Also `select` docs specify you can only have one empty option with an empty string as value

Comment: how would i put it in the scope?

Comment: Can you reproduce that error on this plunker..? http://plnkr.co/edit/fcQWAC6XyEVRWAQvPQK2?p=preview

Comment: i can do one better. It is running on my test site. texasicecarving.com  username: admin password: adminadmin   double click on a Job and the error will show in the console

Comment: did you get a chance to look at it?